# How do you set specific properties to a class created by an abstract factory?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, factory-pattern

Is it possible to have concrete factories create concrete classes with type specific parameters for them, using the abstract factory pattern? Or do the different concrete classes created by their respective concrete factories need to to have the same fields?

Ex) In the image below how would you go about to instantiate the WinButton and the OSXButton with different set of arguments given by the client (Application)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches to address such problems is to send object parameters. Example, in C# Object is the base class & you can pass parameter of type Object which can take any derived class. In the implementation, this object can be casted back to the desired derived type. Even specific properties can be set this way.

Comment: Using the Object class as generic type and then casting it to a specific class is not a very good solution since it isn't type safe and it violates at least one  object-oriented principle namely the Liskov substitution principle. Besides, the concrete classes to create might require a different number of arguments for their respective construction.

Comment: I agree, it is not type safe. Regarding different number of arguments, you can have a type which is composed of other types.

Comment: You mean a data structure where you store creation arguments for the different concrete types? In this case the data structure would have to be changed every time you add a new fabric.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy without having more details. One thing I would do, is to try to pass the arguments to constructor of the concrete factory class. For different arguments you would have to create different factory instance, which might not be the best solution, but as said, this depends on details.

Example:

```
    GUIFactory factory = new WinFactory(WIN_9x_THEME);
    Button greyButton = factory.createButton();
    factory = new WinFactory(WIN_VISTA_THEME, 50);
    Button semiTransparentButton = factory.createButton();
```

Comment: This is one way of doing it but you're sort of missing the abstractness of the pattern since, as you pointed out, the factory classes would have to be reinstantiated for each set of new argument values. You might as well instantiate the concrecte classes directly instead of going through the factory classes.

Comment: @Christian: not really... if you know the combinations of sets of arguments during coding, you can have factories for factories - this gets a bit complex, so maybe a solution based on Dependency Injection makes more sense. In the end it all depends on the specific language and application.

Comment: hmmm...factories of factories; do you maybe have a code example? About it depending on language and application, isn't patterns supposed to be language and application agnostic?

Comment: @Christian: first to the patterns - they are not by definition. Every pattern has its context in which it is applicable. For example Abstract Factory is applicable if you want to create families of objects. If you want to create very different WinButtons and OSXButtons, maybe Abstract Factory is not the right thing. When it comes to languages, many language concepts solve the problems of some patterns directly and so make them obsolete in that language. Example might be multimethods and monkeypatching, which solves similar things as the Visitor pattern.

Comment: @Christian: now to the factories. Without stating your problem it is hard to say what is good, factories of factories might not be good for you. If you want to understand different ways of using factories, good explanations are in the Head First Design Patterns books.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a specific problem at hand, I just want to understand the benefits and limitations of the pattern. I'll check out the Head First Design pattern book.