# How to model this scenario using OOP? (inheritance issue)

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, interface

I have a lot of different engines that implement different algorithms. All of them implement the same interface but have different Configuration methods. Most of them are configured without parameters, some of them with one integer and even less with two integers. There is a small probability that in the future we will have with three or even four integers.

I need to create a Engine controller that decides when it has to start or stop the engine as this is common for all of them. The options I thought are the following:

1. Create an unique interface with as much parameters as the biggest Configure method available and ignore the not needed ones at the engines. This way I'll have just only one EngineController.
2. Create an Interface for each of the different configure methods and create a EngineController for each one of the different interfaces (but this will make me create a lot of classes that only differ on the number of parameters and will require 2 new classes each time a new parameter is added to an engine.
3. ...

I really don't feel comfortable with any of the two solutions as passing unneeded parameters looks 'ugly' and due to the high number of classes generated with the second option (that only have very minor differences).

Any design or pattern that avoids this problem?

### EDIT (Thanks for the answers, this edit answers all of them and clarifies the question):

Just to give an example, these are the engines.

```
abstract class EngineBase
{
    public void Start() {...}
    public void Stop() {...}
}

class EngineOne : EngineBase
{
    public void Configure(int parameter1) {...};
}

class EngineTwo : EngineBase
{
    public void Configure(int parameter1, int parameter2) {...};
}

class EngineThree : EngineBase
{
    public void Configure(int parameter1, int parameter2, int parameter3) {...};
}
```

As all the engines have the same logic to decide when to start or end I want to create a new class that handles them, called EngineController. The controller will call the Configure, the Start and the Stop when needed:

```
class EngineController
{
    EngineBase _engine; ??? or what?

    void SuperviseEngine() { ... _engine.Configure(x,x,...) ... _engine.Start() ... 
}
```

The first idea I has is to add to the EngineBase class the next method:

```
abstract class EngineBase
{
    public void Start() {...}
    public void Stop() {...}
    public void Configure(int parameter1, int parameter2, int parameter3) {...}
}

class EngineController
{
    EngineBase _engine;

    void SuperviseEngine() { ... _engine.Configure(x,y,z) ... _engine.Start() ... 
}
```

and ignore the unneeded parameters but I don't like the idea. Then I thought on doing the following:

```
interface I1ParameterConfigurable
{
    public void Configure(int parameter1) {...};
}

interface I2ParameterConfigurable
{
    public void Configure(int parameter1, int parameter2) {...};
}

interface I3ParameterConfigurable
{
    public void Configure(int parameter1, int parameter2, int parameter3) {...};
}
```

and then create 3 different controllers for each kind of engine:

```
class EngineController1Parameter
{
    EngineBase _engine;
    I1ParameterConfigurable _configurableEngine = _engine as I1ParameterConfigurable;

    void SuperviseEngine() { ... _configurableEngine .Configure(x) ... _engine.Start()
}

class EngineController2Parameter
{
    EngineBase _engine;
    I2ParameterConfigurable _configurableEngine = _engine as I2ParameterConfigurable;

    void SuperviseEngine() { ... _configurableEngine .Configure(x, y) ... _engine.Start()
}
```

You get the idea, but I feel that this will create a lot of interfaces / classes when maybe there is way to avoid this.

Thanks to your answers I have a third option that is similar to the 1st one but using an array (or IEnumerable or whatever) to pass a undefined number of parameters. The idea is not bad but then I'll lose the parameter names. But maybe it's the best option until now.

Comment: code sample please? A simplified one, Id just like to see your interfaces and classes

Comment: Option 1 sounds bad, will be confusing to use and maintain.

Comment: I had a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144397/how-do-you-set-specific-properties-to-a-class-created-by-an-abstract-factory) along the same lines.

Answer (score 2):

Will that help you.

```
    interface IEngine
    {
        void startEngine(params int[] engineParam);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a new idea but ... that way I won't have the parameter names. I will add this as the 3rd option

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't fully understand but I think you want something like this:

```
public interface IEngineController //I dont see a need to expose the enigine here in this pseudo code
{
    void Start(); 
    IConfiguration Config { get; }
}

public interface IEngine
{
    void Start();
}

public interface IConfiguration
{
    bool IsOkToStart { get; }
}

public class Configuration : IConfiguration
{
    public Configuration(List<IConfigurationParameter> configurationParameters)
    {
        ConfigurationParameters = configurationParameters;
    }

    public bool IsOkToStart
    {
        get { return ConfigurationParameters.All(cfg=>cfg.IsOkToStart); }
    }
    protected List<IConfigurationParameter> ConfigurationParameters { get; private set; }
}

public interface IConfigurationParameter
{
    bool IsOkToStart { get; }
}

public interface IMaxTemp : IConfigurationParameter
{
    double MaxTemp { get; }
}

public interface ISafetyParameter : IConfigurationParameter
{
    ISafetyCondition SafetyCondition { get; }
}
```

This got a little long, I omitted Stop() for brevity. The idea is:

- The controller has an IEngine (not exposed in the interface) and an IConfig
- IEngine has the Start() method.
- A Configuration is a list of IConfigparameters that has a bool is ok to start (if all parameters are ok).
- Each parameter has an IsOkToStart that is calculated depending on some condition
  Maybe this provides flexibility for you? Combine the parameters you need and possibly add ned parameters in the future. I believe it is a good thing that the interfaces are extremely small and cohesive. Maybe even split them into IStartParameter and IStopParameter and just combine to the desired config?

Comment: Can you take a look at my new example, maybe it clarifies things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would model it similar to this:

```
 public interface IEngine1 {

 }

 public interface IEngine1Config {
     int Param1 {get;}
 }

 public Engine1 : IEngine1 {
     IEngine1Config _config;
     public Engine1(IEngine1Config config) {
        _config = config;
     }
 }
```

You could then optionally choose to have one class implementing the different engine configurations:

```
 class AllEnginesConfig : IEngine1Config, IEngine2Config {
      int Param1 {get;set;}
      // ... etc
 }
```

(of course, it may be better in your situation to implement the configs in separate classes also)

If you have a lot of engines, I would use an IoC container to register all the different types, and let it wire up all the dependencies.

```
 container.Register<IEngine1, Engine1>();
 var theOneAndOnlyConfig = new AllEnginesConfig() {}; // properly initialized, of course
 container.RegisterInstance<IEngine1Config>(theOneAndOnlyConfig); 
 container.RegisterInstance<IEngine2Config>(theOneAndOnlyConfig); 
 // ...
```

Then, to instantiate an engine, you simply use the container:

```
 container.Get<IEngine1>();
```

Comment: I think that this solution is more or less the same than my 2nd option. Do you agree? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Essentially true, but with some smart IoC container registration conventions, the effort for adding additional engines and configurations is limited to just adding the engine class and extending the configuration class if needed.

Answer (score 0):

IOC containers to invoke a engine you require or bunch of engines you require and inject them at run time and you can use them in combination with optional parameters while invoking containers. I have seen usage of Optional parameters in many attributes of .NET FW. or use an list of object parameter to get all inputs and when called can parse the list and decide which engine it was intended to invoke. None of them will be hard to grasp and use

Comment: I'm not sure on how IoC can help here.